# Django @login_required 'next' incorrect redirect

Tags: django

My problem is that `@login_required` redirects to root page instead of correct next path.
`/accounts/login/?next=/main/setka/` redirects to `'/'` instead of `/main/setka/` after logging in.

Could anybody assist me?

The code:

Head urls

```
url(r'^main/', include('main.urls')),   
url(r'^accounts/',include('loginsystem.urls')),
```

loginsystem.urls

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

/main/ urls.py

```
(r'^setka/$', views.setka),
```

my link to the corresponding view with the decorator at '/' homepage

```
<li><a href="/main/setka/">Setka</a></li>
```

loginsystem.views

```
@login_required
def setka(request):
    return render_to_response('main/setka.html')
```

login.html includes

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/style.css' %}" />

{% if form.errors %}
<p class="error">Sorry invalid</p>
{% endif %}
<body>
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
<label for="username">User name:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
<label for="password">password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />

</form>
</body>
```

Url chain likes this: 'root/' -> root/accounts/login/?next=/main/setka/ -> '/' instead of 'root/main/setka/'

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**To be specific, I want to dynamically attach 'next' path to root address, but it does not attach 'next' path at all.**

Comment: Should it not be `root/accounts/login/?next=/root/main/setka/` ? Is the URL valid? just check in the browser (It is trying to redirect to `mydomain.com/main/setka/ `)

Comment: @karthikr: We seem to be getting a lot of login url questions, I mean, its all the same things, people should really just do a quick search.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac If you find duplicated questions, feel free to mark it as a duplicate. Sometimes, the search results may not yield the results due to the search terms used

Comment: @vspr i think you have wrote your own login function? If Yes, are you taking care of `next` if it is in `GET`?

Comment: Well not really, if you see the login uses the standard django function .. (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),

Comment: Can you paste the login form that is actually rendered on the browser ... Is that correct

Comment: Added full login.html form. Ty guys. All URLs are valid. Still cannot figure out why 'next' path is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you need to change the `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to your desired path in `settings.py`.

For example:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/accounts/'
```

Comment: Just in case, I do not want to hardcode custom redirect url. I want to dynamically attach 'next' path to root address. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vspr: Then just put a regex in there. No problem.