# django-stronghold not using next parameter for redirecting

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm not sure whether this is a problem with django-stronghold or with django itself.

**What happens:**

- Calling any front end URL (e.g. http://www.myapp.com/careers) leads me to the login page
- The URL shown looks like this: http://www.myapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/careers
- Upon login, I am forwarded to the admin interface (like when logging in at http://www.myapp.com/admin)
- The displayed URL is still http://www.myapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/careers

**What I want:**

- Upon login, I want to be forwarded to the URL called originally, as correctly stored in the next parameter (in the example: http://www.myapp.com/careers)

**My setup:**

I'm using Django 1.6.

As suggested in the [docs](https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold), I have installed django-stronghold via pip and activated it in my project like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'stronghold',  # last entry
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'stronghold.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',  # last entry
]
```

At first, I ran into a redirect loop, so I defined the STRONGHOLD_PUBLIC_URLS:

```
STRONGHOLD_PUBLIC_URLS = (
    r'^/admin.*?$',  # Don't touch the admin pages
    r'^/accounts/login/$',  # Avoid redirect loop
)
```

**What I tried:**

- Explicitly setting LOGIN_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616812/461544) - didn't help.
- In the context of logging into the admin interface, django's login mechanism works fine, just like it is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login):

> Here’s what **django.contrib.auth.views.login** does:
>
> - If called via **GET**, it displays a login form that POSTs to the same URL. [...]
> - If called via **POST** with user submitted credentials, it tries to log the user in. If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in **next**. [...]

- If I call an admin URL other than .../admin (e.g. http://www.myapp.com/admin/myapp_base/event/), the displayed URL remains the same while the login form is shown (no next parameter). After logging in, I see the requested page.

**Ideas?**

Any ideas why the redirect isn't working for the front end URLs?